# Regular Expression to deny input of repeated characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I want a regular expression which allows the uses to enter the following values. Minimum of **Four** and max of **30** characters and first character should be **Upper Case**.

**Eg: John, Smith, Anderson, Emma**

And I don't want the user to input the following types of values

**Jooohnnnnnn, Smmmmith, Aaaanderson, Emmmmmmmmma**

Can any one provide me with a regular expression? I search for quite some time but can't find working RegEx.

I need it for my ASP.net MVC application Model validation.

Thanks

Edited: I don't know how to check for repeated characters I just tried the following

`@"^[A-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z ]{2,29}$"`

The rules that I would like to add are

```
  1. First character Upper case
  2. 4-30 characters
  3. No repeats of characters. Not greater than 2
```

Comment: Can you include your attempted regex? Also, why is Emma authorized?

Comment: Two repeats can be allowed

Comment: @RandomUser Can you edit your post to make it more explicit? The exact rules you're trying to enforce are not clear.

Comment: BTW, `{1}` is always useless. By default, a character is here once.

Answer (score 7):

To perform a check on your regex you can use a negative look ahead:

```
^(?!.*(.)\1{2})[A-Z][a-zA-Z ]{3,29}$
```

The look ahead `(?!...)` will fail the whole regex if what's inside it matches.

To look for repeated patterns, we use a capture group: `(.)\1{2}`. We capture the first character, then check if it is followed by (at least) two identical characters with the backreference `\1`.

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/rK7qX5).

Comment: How can I do the same for email ID, to deny `xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx` I tried to add `(?!.*(.)\1{2})` with what I have but it didn't work.

Comment: @RandomUser: What's your regex for the email?

Comment: `@"^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"+@"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."+ @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"+ @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$"`

Comment: **1** For inline code, please use backticks: \` **2** If this is the exact same situation as this question I may help you, if not you should probably ask a different question. Comments aren't designed for extended back & forth. **3** Can you provide an example email that shows your issue? I guess one that is validated by this regex, with 3 consecutive characters, and it still validated by the regex when you add `(?!.*(.)\1{2})` at the beginning.

Comment: Will as a new question

Comment: That was nice on the eyes, Robin! `(?!.*(.)\1{2})` +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
^               (?# Starting of name)
 (?=[A-Z])      (?# Ensure it starts with capital A-Z without consuming the text)
 (?i:([a-z])    (?# Following letters ignoring case)  
    (?!\1{2,})  (?# Letter cant be followed by previous letter more than twice)
 ){3,30}        (?# Allow condition to be repeated 3 to 30 times)
$
```

Visual representation would look like follow:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: No idea if that's actually an issue, but FYI it will also match `Mmmatthew`